# What is the meaning of "find%4==0"?

Tags: if-statement, while-loop, fwrite, fread

```
void searchcontact()
{
    int l,i;
    char query[20];
    system("cls");
    do
    {
        find=0;
        printf("Contact Search\n Name of the Contact:\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%[^\n]",&query);
        l=strlen(query);
        f=fopen("contact.txt","r");

        system("cls");
        printf("Search the result for %s\n",query);
        while(fread(&add,sizeof(add),3,f)==1)
        {
            for(i=0;i<=3;i++)
            name[i]=add.name[i];
            name[l]='\0';
            if(stricmp(name,query)==0)
            {
                printf("Name\t:%s\nPhone\t:%d\nE-mail\t:%s\n",add.name,add.hpnum,add.email);
                find++;
                if(find%4==0)
                {
                    printf("Press any key to continue");
                    getch();
                }
            }
        }
        if(find==0)
        printf("\nNo match found!");
        else
        printf("\n %d match(s) found",find);
        fclose(f);
        printf("\nTry again?\t[1] Yes\t[2] No\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
    }while(choice==1);
}
```

This is my contact system project...anyone know `find%4==0` means? I doesn't know due to this part of coding I refer to somewhere else. Therefore I can't understand what the find%4==0 means, can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 2):

In general, `x % y == z` is `True` when `x / y` has a remainder equal to `z`.

In this case, `find % 4 == 0` is `True` when the variable `find` is divisible by `4` (has no remainder).

Answer (score 1):

It is a modulo operator: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Basically, when x is divided by 4 it returns the remainder.

Comment: It makes the code pause after every 4 matches. I guess so the user can read them.

Comment: @LeoJieHui This is too basic to be asked here, every decent C++ tutorial/reference should mention operators...

Answer (score 1):

It is the modulo operator. It means, when you test it against `0`, is `find` divisible by 4.